# How can I parse ruby json request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm using api request/response on my rails app. To update avatar i've got this request(i took it from development.log file)

```
Started PUT "/user/avatars.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-18 11:47:57 +0300
Processing by AvatarsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe6cbedae18 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/n3/5_nb_zks2k91r5ngcmb4fm9r0000gn/T/RackMultipart20170718-26576-1vss7hh.png>, @original_filename="Снимок экрана 2017-07-16 в 21.55.05.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"avatar\"; filename=\"\xD0\xA1\xD0\xBD\xD0\xB8\xD0\xBC\xD0\xBE\xD0\xBA \xD1\x8D\xD0\xBA\xD1\x80\xD0\xB0\xD0\xBD\xD0\xB0 2017-07-16 \xD0\xB2 21.55.05.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}
```

Now, I need to send this request from POSTMAN application. But it uses ruby syntax like ***=>***. How can I convert it to json to use in POSTMAN?

Comment: Have you tried to set `Content-Type` header to `application/octet-stream` and send your file via form-data?
Also, AFAIK, there're some troubles with file upload with Postman, [github issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1991)

Answer (score 1):

http://3dml.free.fr/rubyhashconverter/

I don't know if you need to do it within your code or not, but the above is an online converter, takes ruby hash syntax (old and new) and gives valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

JSON doesn't support binary data(images). So in order to pass the image, you need to convert image to base64 string and use it in JSON.

[image: Example API Uploading an image]